# algorithm complexity from O(n)squre to O(n)cube

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, time-complexity

I am doing a study at the university i need to change the time complexity of the below algorithm from algorithm complexity from O(n)square to O(n)cube to do some measures

```
public class bubble_sort_alg {

public void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {

    boolean swapped = true;

    int j = 0;

    int tmp;

    while (swapped) {

        swapped = false;

        j++;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - j; i++) {

            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {

                tmp = arr[i];

                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];

                arr[i + 1] = tmp;

                swapped = true;

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Add another loop in the innermost `for`-loop that accesses all items of your array that has no side effects on your algorithm and you'll get cubic complexity.

Comment: O(n^2) is a *subset* of O(n^3). Thus your algorithm is already O(n^3).

Answer (score 2):

`Why do you want to do that ?`

If this is your requirement then inside `for` loop again iterate over all the item `(arr.length)` this will produce n cube complexity

Comment: +1 You can always add a loop anywhere (at the start if you wish) to increase the time complexity to anything you like.

Comment: Actually, doing nothing will also produce `O(n^3)` complexity, since `O(n^2)` is a *subset* of `O(n^3)`